# MSSQL - Update statement different result based on SSMS version

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table that fires a trigger when a record gets updated. When I update the record using a DML-statement using SSMS 18.4 the transaction is rolled back because of the error `'A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow results from triggers' is true.'`

When I fire the same statement from SSMS 11.03 the update is stored without throwing the error message above.

Below is the trigger code:

```
    DECLARE     @iCntrMTL varchar(20),
            @iCntrLOD varchar(20), 
            @iCntrWeight int, 
            @iCntrID int,
            @iCntrEmpty bit,
            @iCntrDestination varchar(150), 
            @iCntrDestBOLLOD varchar(20),
            @iCntrEmptyWeight int,
            @iCntrToFill bit,
            @iCntrUseForLoading bit,
            @pCntrMTL varchar(20),
            @pCntrLOD varchar(20), 
            @pCntrWeight int, 
            @pCntrID int, 
            @pCntrEmpty bit,
            @pCntrDestination varchar(150), 
            @pCntrDestBOLLOD varchar(20),
            @pCntrEmptyWeight int,
            @pCntrToFill bit,
            @pCntrUseForLoading bit,
            @AuditText varchar(2500)

select * into #inserted from inserted 

if update(cntrweight) or update(cntrMTL) or update(cntrlod) or update(CntrDestination) or update(CntrDestBOLLOD) or update(cntrempty)
    or update(cntruseforloading) or update(cntrtofill) or update(cntremptyweight)
    BEGIN
        select  @iCntrid = cntrid, 
                @iCntrMTL = cntrmtl, 
                @icntrlod = cntrlod, 
                @iCntrWeight = CntrWeight, 
                @iCntrDestination = CntrDestination, 
                @iCntrDestBOLLOD = CntrDestBOLLOD,
                @iCntrEmpty = CntrEmpty,
                @iCntrUseForLoading = CntrUseForLoading,
                @iCntrToFill = CntrToFill,
                @iCntrEmptyWeight = CntrEmptyWeight
        from inserted
        select  @pCntrid = cntrid, 
                @pCntrMTL = cntrmtl, 
                @pcntrlod = cntrlod, 
                @pCntrWeight = CntrWeight, 
                @pCntrDestination = CntrDestination, 
                @pCntrDestBOLLOD = CntrDestBOLLOD,
                @pCntrEmpty = CntrEmpty,
                @pCntrUseForLoading = CntrUseForLoading,
                @pCntrToFill = CntrToFill,
                @pCntrEmptyWeight = CntrEmptyWeight
        from deleted

        --select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '#inserted'
        --select * from #inserted
        if @pCntrMTL != @iCntrMTL 
            set @AuditText = isnull(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrMTL=' + isnull(@pCntrMTL,'') + ' -- New.CntrMTL= ' + isnull(@iCntrMTL ,'') + ' || '
        --Set @AuditText = 'Prev.CntrMTL=' + isnull(@pCntrMTL,'') + ' -- New.CntrMTL= ' + isnull(@iCntrMTL ,'') + ' || '
        if @pCntrLOD != @iCntrLOD
            Set @AuditText = isnull(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrLOD=' + isnull(@pCntrLOD,'') + ' -- New.CntrLOD= ' + isnull(@iCntrLOD,'') + ' || '
        if @pCntrWeight != @iCntrWeight
            Set @AuditText = isnull(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrWeight=' + convert(varchar(10),isnull(@pCntrWeight,'')) + ' -- New.CntrWeight= ' + convert(varchar(10),isnull(@iCntrWeight,'')) + ' || ' 
        if @pCntrDestination != @iCntrDestination
            Set @AuditText = isnull(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrDestination=' + isnull(@pCntrDestination,'') + ' -- New.CntrDestination= ' + isnull(@iCntrDestination,'') + ' || '
        if @pCntrDestBOLLOD != @iCntrDestBOLLOD
            Set @AuditText = ISNULL(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrDestBOLLOD=' + isnull(@pCntrDestBOLLOD,'') + ' -- New.CntrDestBOLLOD= ' + isnull(@iCntrDestBOLLOD,'') + ' || '
        if @pCntrEmpty != @iCntrEmpty
            Set @AuditText = ISNULL(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrEmpty=' + cast(@pCntrEmpty as char(1)) + ' -- New.CntrEmpty= ' + cast(@iCntrEmpty as char(1)) + ' || '
        if @pCntrUseForLoading != @iCntrUseForLoading
            Set @AuditText = ISNULL(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrUseForLoading=' + cast(@pCntrUseForLoading as char(1)) + ' -- New.CntrUseForLoading= ' + cast(@iCntrUseForLoading as char(1)) + ' || '
        if @pCntrToFill != @iCntrToFill
            Set @AuditText = ISNULL(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrToFill=' + cast(@pCntrToFill as char(1)) + ' -- New.CntrToFill= ' + cast(@iCntrToFill as char(1)) + ' || '
        if @pCntrEmptyWeight != @iCntrEmptyWeight
            Set @AuditText = ISNULL(@AuditText,'') + 'Prev.CntrEmptyWeight=' + convert(varchar(10),isnull(@pCntrEmptyWeight,'')) + ' -- New.CntrEmptyWeight= ' + convert(varchar(10),isnull(@iCntrEmptyWeight,'')) + ' || '
        IF @AuditText is not null 
            INSERT INTO ContainerMutaties (CmCntrID,CmTimeStamp, CmMutatie, cmcmcName) values (@iCntrid, getdate(), @AuditText, 'CHG')
    END
```

END

If I disable the statement `select * into #inserted from inserted` , which not necessary it still gives the same error.

Can someone explain why the error is thrown in SSMS 18.4 and not in SSMS 11.03 and also which statement is returned from the trigger according the error-message? I would day the `select * into #inserted from inserted` but then when removing it from the trigger it still gives the same error so it must be something else.

Comment: I think i found the root-cause. I had the option 'Include actual Execution Plan' enabled in SSMS. After turning this option off, the update statement ran without an issue in SSMS 18.4. When enabling it in SSMS 11.03 it would fail with the same reason..... For me this is weird but that could be due to the fact this I lack some indepth SQL knowledge....

Comment: Start over. For future reference post ALL the code, not just the body or what you think is the body. It's easy to accidentally forget one line. Next, start over. Your code suffers from a very common flaw. You assume that there is only one row affected by the update (or merge) statement - any number of rows can be affected (from zero! to many). Lastly why do you a pattern for no obvious reason? Why do you create temp tables but never use them? Lastly - "if update" does not do what you assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the root-cause. I had the option 'Include actual Execution Plan' enabled in SSMS. After turning this option off, the update statement ran without an issue in SSMS 18.4. When enabling it in SSMS 11.03 it would fail with the same reason..... For me this is weird but that could be due to the fact this I lack some indepth SQL knowledge

Comment: You should accept this as the answer. I'm sure this will help someone else